# While looping the DataSource in Mattable, the headers are repeating as well

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to append multiple rows into a table while looping the dataSource array, while calling an api to populate the dataSource array in a for loop. But, while looping, the table headers are repeating as well. How can I only repeat only the table rows without repeating the headers? [image: Table]

```html
<table mat-table *ngFor="let dataSource of dataSource" [dataSource]="dataSource" class="tableCss table-striped" style="width: 100%;" matSort #sort="matSort" matTableExporter #exporter="matTableExporter">
  <!-- <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  class="tableCss table-striped" style="width: 100%;" matSort #sort = "matSort" matTableExporter    #exporter="matTableExporter" > -->

  <!-- <div *ngFor="let dataSource of dataSource" [dataSource]="dataSource"> -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="typeId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.typeId}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="typeName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.typeName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="bankAccName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Bank Account Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.bankAccName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="bankAccNo">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Bank Account No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.bankAccNo}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="bankIFSC">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> IFSC code </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.bankIFSC}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="autoBankVerFlag">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Auto Bank Verification Flag </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.autoBankVerFlag}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="autoBankVerDetails">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Auto Bank Verification Details </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.autoBankVerDetails}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="cancelledChequeImg">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Cancelled Cheque Images </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">Image</td>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-container matColumnDef="Edit">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Edit</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="action-link">
      <button class="table-buttons" (click)="openDialog(element, 'agg')"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: #E61748; font-size: 22px;"></i></button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- </div> -->

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns;sticky : true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:   getDisplayedColumns();"></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not have ngFor on table element, MatTable will automatically handle it using dataSource Property.

Change below code

```
<table mat-table *ngFor="let dataSource of dataSource" [dataSource]="dataSource"  class="tableCss table-striped" style="width: 100%;" matSort #sort = "matSort" matTableExporter    #exporter="matTableExporter" >
```

to

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  class="tableCss table-striped" style="width: 100%;" matSort #sort = "matSort" matTableExporter    #exporter="matTableExporter" >
```

Comment: But then I'm getting an empty data. DataSource is declared like:   dataSource = [];

Comment: And that will be the expected behavior, when you don't have no date in array then it should be empty.